# Box-shadow not shown on Safari Mobile on iOS 7 (in landscape)

Tags: css, ipad, ios7, mobile-safari

I have a very simple `box-shadow` on an header:

```
h1 {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 9px -8px #000000;
    color: #D95B43;
    height: 1.2em;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

But the box-shadow doesn't work on Mobile Safari (iOS 7). In the previous version (and in **portrait view**, in iOS7) it works fine.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

And a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNcV3/).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: iPhone 5 iOS 7.0.4, Safari everything works fine

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Adding `border-radius: 1px` fixed the problem:

```
h1 {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 9px -8px #000000;
    border-radius: 1px;
    color: #D95B43;
    height: 1.2em;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21323644/1565597 .

Comment: I have a box shadow on a full-width div that was sporadically showing on phone iOS, though it seemed fine on the iPad. This 1px radius fixed the issue for me as well. Thank you!

Comment: What the heck! ..... it's not 'logically' related to box-shadow, fortunately it solved my issue ....

Answer (score 28):

Try the following CSS property:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Comment: Excellent! Solved an issue of subtle box-shadow not appearing on iPad on iOS 11.

Comment: Why does this work?  I was having problems using a box-shadow in place of a border in safari mobile, but adding this line fixed it.  Edit: I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/26687797/1435658 which explains it.

Answer (score 5):

I tried reading the `Bootstrap` code.
Maybe set the following code will solve it.

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try prefixing the box-shadow with the right vendor prefix. In this case:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 9px -8px #000000;
```

Works for me in your jsfiddle.

Note: If you want your css3 to be fail-proof on other browsers, refer here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#vendor-keyword-history for a list of prefixes. Most important are `-o-`, `-moz-`, `-ms-`, and `-webkit-`

Comment: I already tried that, it didn't work. What version of Safari do you have?

Comment: Worked in portrait and I missed your note about that.